# Why NW.js major version is still 0?

Tags: versioning, nwjs

Simple question about versioning numbers related to NW.js.

Why NW.js major version is still 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I really don't know.** I've been using it since 0.11 and I can say that it should have had major bumps here:

- Probably around `0.7.3`, I would say this was at a fairly stable point, and had a lot more features than most other similar tools (see: [XPDA.net](https://xpda.net) for comparison), to call the project `1.0.0`
- `0.12.3` = Last version of the original architecture. Should have been `1.5.3`.
- `0.13.0` = Should have been a major bump, `2.0.0`. It was a completely new architecture, rebranding from Node-Webkit to NW.js, and major API changes. The architecture and API change from here (2013) is still used today. Updating a project from 0.13.0 to 0.51.0 (latest stable) may not require any code changes at all, you'd just get a ton of new features and security patches from chromium/node.
- `0.14.7` = This is the LTS version that still supports Win XP, and OSX 10.6. Should have been `2.2.7`.
- `0.15.0` = Should have been `3.0.0` (to indicate breaking change of OS support, though API is the same).
- Some time between `0.20.0` and `0.30.` the OSX version support changed from 10.6 to 10.9. There was some other OS support changes that were a result of Chromium and Node. For example, Node 13+ may work on Windows 7, but it is no longer supported, so it also may not. So probably a bump to `4.0.0` around here for the OS version support change to be more obvious and better documented.
- `0.42.4` = This was the first release with NW2 enabled by default, a major re-write to the window system that would allow tons of new Chromium features to be added in the future. This should have been another major bump to `5.0.0`.

So if your question is **"Is it production ready?"** then, yes, since 2013, and you could even argue it was pretty capable back in 2011 when compared to a lot of other modern (2021) efforts.

If your questions is **"Is it stable?"** then, yes, since 2016 there have been no breaking changes to the API. Just constant and consistent updates to Chromium and Node.js, and new features being added.

It seems like they do "minor" bumps any time they update chromium to a new Major number, and do "patch" bumps anytime they update Chromium or Node.js without changing the major Chromium number. Which has at least some logic to it.

---

**EDIT:** I've written a more in depth and detailed article on NW.js versions:

- https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/guide-to-nw-js-versions-5d38

Comment: Good! Now I am more confident on NW.js. Thanks!